# Upper bounded wildcard is causing compilation error

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Integer(21));
    }

}
```

What is the compilation error in line#4?

Comment: What exception you getting? Did you try it?

Comment: he method add(capture#1-of ? extends Integer) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)

Comment: `? extends Something` is a producer... You cannot **add** values to it... (You can actually add `null` which doesnt make sense anyway).